# Set a background image for NSWindow using Cocoascript

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, javascriptcore, cocoascript, sketchapp

I'm trying to create a window in this style:

[image]

I have the following code, but I just get a back background. I guess it can't find the image.

```
var win = [[NSWindow alloc] init]
[win setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 320, 200) display:false]
[win setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

I'm writing this for a [Sketch App plugin](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/01-introduction/01.html) so I have to use [Cocoascript](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/01-introduction/05.html). My plugin structure looks like

```
myplugin.sketchplugin/
    Contents/
        Sketch/
            app.js
            manifest.json
        Resources/
            background.png
```

I'm neither sure where to put the background image or how to reference it. Would it have to be in manifest.json? Under which key?

Answer (score 1):

*(I don't use Sketch so this is untested)*

[Here](https://github.com/BohemianCoding/ExampleSketchPlugins/blob/master/Hello%20World/Hello%20World.sketchplugin/Contents/Sketch/script.cocoascript) is an example how to load `World.pdf` that resides in the `Resources` folder.

It basically does this:

```
var plugin = context.plugin;// the plugin (MSPluginBundle)
var imageLayer = SketchLib.addImageLayer(group, {"name": "World", "url": [plugin urlForResourceNamed:"World.pdf"]})
```

So if `[plugin urlForResourceNamed:"World.pdf"]` does the job I suspect that

`[plugin urlForResourceNamed:"background.png"]` should also.